# Convert "nvarchar" column data type to "DateTime'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know how to convert the column data type from "**`nvarchar`**" format to "**`datetime`**" in SQL Server?

**Ex:**

1. `01-06-2020 12:00:00 AM`
2. `6-17-2020 12:00:00 AM`

I've tried the below query:

`ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN UpdatedDate datetime`

But, got the below error

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: You have bad values.

Answer (score 6):

Well, Now that you've seen how problematic it might be, I hope you've learned never to store `DateTime` values as strings.
You should strive to always use the most appropriate data type available.
Don't worry, though. It's such a common mistake Aaron Bertrand wrote a blog post about it (well, the more general problem) - called [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

So here's how you deal with this sort of thing:
(TL;DR; Live demo on [<kbd>Rextester</kbd>](https://rextester.com/LNE78137))

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Id int identity(1,1),
    UpdatedDate nvarchar(30)
);


INSERT INTO MyTable(UpdatedDate) VALUES
('01-06-2020 12:00:00 AM'),
('6-17-2020 12:00:00 AM'),
('02-30-2020 12:00:00 AM'), -- Bad data
('1-06-2020 12:00:00 ZM'),  -- Bad data
('01-06-2020 13:00:00 PM'),
('13-06-2020 13:00:00 PM'),  -- Bad data
('01-06-2020 1:00:00 PM'),
('1-6-2020 1:00:00 AM'),
('Not a date at all...');  -- Bad data
```

Notice I've added some rows that contains data that can't be converted to a `DateTime` value.

Then, the First step is to get a list of values that will fail convert.

```
SELECT Id, UpdatedDate
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DateTime2, UpdatedDate, 110) IS NULL;
```

This will return the following recordset (for this sample data):

```
Id  UpdatedDate
3   02-30-2020 12:00:00 AM
4   1-06-2020 12:00:00 ZM
6   13-06-2020 13:00:00 PM
9   Not a date at all...
```

Now that you have the list, you can decide whether you want to manually fix them, delete the records,
or simply ignore the values, leaving the new `UpdatedDate` column `NULL` in these rows.

After you're done, you add a new column to the table, with a temporary name.
I suggest using `DateTime2` and not `DateTime` - [it's just a better data type.](https://hockeygeekgirl.com/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
ADD UpdatedDate_New DateTime2 NULL;
```

Next, you populate this column (I'm assuming here you've decided to leave it null where the original column's data can't be converted to `DateTime2`):

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET  UpdatedDate_New = TRY_CONVERT(DateTime2, UpdatedDate, 110);
```

Now, remove the old column from the table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
DROP COLUMN UpdatedDate;
```

And finally, Rename the new column:

```
EXEC sp_Rename 'dbo.MyTable.UpdatedDate_New', 'UpdatedDate', 'COLUMN';
```

Validate the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable
```

Results:

```
Id  UpdatedDate
1   06.01.2020 00:00:00
2   17.06.2020 00:00:00
3   NULL
4   NULL
5   06.01.2020 13:00:00
6   NULL
7   06.01.2020 13:00:00
8   06.01.2020 01:00:00
9   NULL
```

There is one last issue I haven't addressed in this answer and that's the dependencies of the original column. You should check what depends on the original column, because sometimes you will have to make adjustments to code depending on the column you've changed.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setting for `dateformat`:

```
create table t(dt varchar(10));

insert t(dt) select '20/7/2020';

set dateformat mdy;

alter table t alter column dt datetime ;
--error

set dateformat dmy;

alter table t alter column dt datetime;
-- ok, because the format of the dates in the table is dmy
```

In your case, your values are in the format month/day/year. So you need to execute `set dateformat mdy`

Comment: That's assuming all the values are, in fact, valid. That's very hard to ensure with `nvarchar` data type. What's to stop the user from entering `13-35-1000 Ba:na:na AM`?

Comment: Nothing, but then you obviously can't convert the column to a datetime, you would have to do some data cleansing first.

Comment: Hence the usage of `Try_convert` on my answer, and the first step of identifying bad data...

Comment: Sure. But this question is about how to convert from one to the other, not about how to do the data cleansing. I would pull the data that contains invalid dates, give it to the business, make the corrections, and then convert the column. We can't simply assume we can throw the data away.

Comment: If you read carefully, I've written that there are basically two options: Either fix the corrupt data manually, or ignore and dump it (either with the entire row or without). True, the better option is to fix the corrupt data, however that's not always an option (Imagine a small table with only half a million records, where 1 percent of them has incorrect updatedDate values. That's 5,000 rows to sip through manually. Not really a lovely option now, is it?

Comment: Anyways, my point is that your answer might still leave the OP hanging, because DateFormat might not be the problem at all. The sample data provided in the question isn't enough to conclude anything - so I went with the worst possible scenario when I wrote my answer.

Comment: I didn't say it was a lovely option. But it's not the call of the programmer. It's up to the owners of the data, which is almost always the business, not the programmers. If the business says "go ahead and throw away all of the invalid dates", then go ahead and throw away all the invalid dates. If they want to do something else, do something else. It's their call, not ours.

Comment: If the solution doesn't work OP can ask a different question about "how to find invalid dates".

Comment: Now who is stepping outside the scope? :-) Of course the owners of the data is the one that should decide - but that's not a technical issue... Anyways, We're side tracking here and probably should stop before some moderator throws this entire conversation to the chat.

Comment: It's still you stepping outside of the scope. The scope of this question is how to do the conversion, and why it appears to be failing in this case. I am explicitly saying that the data cleansing is not in this scope. Your criticism is rather silly, since you have exactly the same problem with your solution: You had to make exactly the same assumption about the format of the dates. Your `try_convert` expression assumes a format. How do you know whether '1/2/2020' is the first of feb, or the second of jan?

Comment: I've assumed, perhaps wrongly, that the sample data provided by the OP is of valid dates (otherwise, if the OP knows the data is invalid, the question should have been "how to fix bad data"). Based on that assumption I've concluded the most probable format.

Comment: Exactly. As have I :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Month/Day/Year format. As below example you can see:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TABLE1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TABLE1
GO
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (myDate NVARCHAR(128))
GO
INSERT TABLE1 VALUES('01-06-2020 12:00:00 AM'), ('6-17-2020 12:00:00 AM')
GO
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
GO
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ALTER COLUMN myDate DATETIME
GO
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

In this dataset, it will be work fine.

Comment: That's assuming all the values are, in fact, valid. That's very hard to ensure with `nvarchar` data type. What's to stop the user from entering `13-35-1000 Ba:na:na AM`?